# A number theory problem [Permutation]

Tags: number-theory, permutations, contest-math

Let $(a_1, a_2, a_3, . . . , a_{2011})$ be a permutation (that is a rearrangement) of the numbers $1, 2, 3, . . . , 2011.$ Show that there exist two numbers $j,k$ such that $1 \le j < k \le 2011$ and$|a_j - j| = |a_k-k|$

Comment: As a suggestion:  try it for numbers smaller than $2011$ first.

Comment: This looks like a job for the Pigeonhole Principle.

Comment: I know the answer via the pigeonhole principle, but I am wondering if I can find a solution by induction.

Comment: @Shaun I was thinking that too, but I also know there's over 2 million possible selections of the indices.

Comment: I have concluded that the summation of $|a_j-j|$ has to be even

Comment: I am kinda clueless here. How about you guys help me instead of downvoting my question?

Comment: people tend to downvote if they see no effort maybe look up pigeonhole principle on wikipedia ??

Comment: @LinuxGeek The downvotes are probably coming because your question is stated as is, and seemingly with no thought or effort from your side, although that is reflected in your comments. Also, the use of $2011$ reminds people of a contest problem, so they may  think you have copied. BUT THAT ASIDE, if $|a_j - j| \neq |a_k - k|$ for all $j \neq k$, then as sets, $\{|a_j-j|\} = \{1,2,3,...,2010\}$, because there are only $2010 $ possible values of $|a_j-j|$.  Summing over these, and using the summation formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ gives a contradiction. This sum will be odd.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг 0 is also possible. also it's tagged contest math ...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee  Ah, good point. But that wouldn't change the sum, so the contradiction still remains true.

Comment: another thing would be to show that not all possible values can happen in the same permutation if not then you can say you have under 2011 values to match up  with 2011 indices at least one value must happen at two or more of the indices.

Comment: In order to remove this from unanswered queue, I have copy pasted the required link. Now it is a reasonable step to close this question by whatever reason you consider legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it wasn't hard to identify the problem for me. I have solved almost all past papers of RMO Delhi/Mumbai region. [This is one of them.](http://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/olympiads/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/rmo-2011-solutions.pdf). See problem $2$.

Comment: Whatever reason considered  legitimate, your link has more to like than the  solutions. Therefore, +1/ Especially the sixth question.

Comment: This is where I came from sir. I couldn't get the solution at first, though now it seems trivial. I only wanted another solution like the ones discussed in the comment. I am preparing for RMO 2017

Comment: @ LinuxGeek First of all I am not a sir (I maybe one or two year older than you), secondly best of luck for RMO $2017$

Comment: @VidyanshuMishra I am 14

Comment: Ha ha... I am $16$ and a half. @LinuxGeek